# RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error,The error occurred while I was taking all the values for this variable using dt.variables['time'][:]

Tags: python, netcdf

The error occurred while I was taking all the values for this variable using **dt.variables['time'][:]**

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
    for j in range(len(lat)):
        for k in range(len(lon)):
        # the error occurred
             all_datas.append([ls[i],lat[j],lon[k],tasmax[i][j][k]-273.15])
```

The environment is as follows：

- netcdf4                   1.6.2            py37hda396d2_0
- hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
- hdf5                      1.10.6               h1756f20_1
- Python 3.7.16
- Windows 11

1,I try to find the specific data where the error occurs through traversal such as :print(i,j,k,tasmin[i][j][k]).Once found, replace the data with the previous one,tasmin[i-1][j][k]
2,then I try to solve this trouble by this way:

```
                    try:
                        all_datas.append([ls[i],lat[j],lon[k],tasmin[i][j][k]-273.15])
                    except:
                        all_datas.append([ls[i],lat[j],lon[k],tasmin[i-1][j][k]-273.15])
```

I do not how to solve this trouble by other ways.Welcome to discuss with me!

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible to others. A code chunk that won’t reproduce the issue is not enough